# Displaying a DIV from different url in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a list of recent post list and I'm trying to load a post's specific div part in pop up in WordPress. Assuming I have the post link:
`<?php the_permalink() ?>` now I want to load the content of div id="this" from post in pop up when I click the link of recent post links. I've tried iframe but can't find the solution. The problem isn't the pop-up, I'm looking to get the content of specific div id from the post.

Comment: If you are doing this server side, can't you just print the content of the div in the popup the same way wordpress populates the content of that div when you load the post? If you just want to display a div that can be problematic if you want to include the style of the div since the style is a function of the context it has in the document (per css). If you just want to display the text content of the div it's easier. Please clarify further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `.load()`. Note that `id` in `document` should be unique.

```
  $("#button").on("click", function() {
    $("#element").load("/path/to/html #id", function() {
      console.log($("#id"))
    });
  });
```